# "Google is asking for my phone number" Is the tense correct here?

Tags: past-tense

I have seen  people use sentences like-"Google is asking for my phone number (for verification)". But shouldn't it be "Google has asked for my phone number" because if a person receives such a notification from Google,then that event has happened in the past?

Comment: "is asking" sounds like the request is pending, or persistent.

Answer (score 1):

The sense of

> Google is asking for my phone number.

is usually that the question has been asked, but an answer not yet given.

In the same way the phrase:

> I am asking you a question.

implies I have asked a question, and haven't received an answer yet. E.g.

> A: Did you drink the last of the milk?
>
> B: I don't like that green top milk.
>
> A: I am asking you a question.

In both cases the request or the question has not been answered, so is on-going.

Answer (score 0):

Either expression fits, if the recent past is meant. I could say
"You are asking a question about the tense used for something that is probably a recent event.", even though you actually asked several minutes ago.
If you had posed the question last week, I'd be more likely to use "You asked..." or "You have asked...", but it's just a matter of perspective.

On the other hand, if you  have already answered Google's question, and it's not an open question, you wouldn't say "they are asking", unless you meant in a general sense, like this:
"Guess what! Google is now asking for phone numbers for verification."